# Disabling the Geolocation Allow Deny notification in browsers

Tags: javascript, browser

Hey guys i have a requirement which needs me to show the GeoLocation of client like the longitude,latitude etc etc..,but my browser chrome/mozilla asks for a notification at the top under the address bar asking for my permission to allow to share my location with the site im developing.But my client dosenot want that notification to appear,is their any way or workaround in javascript through which i can bypass that notification at client(browser) and just directly display the o/p to end user.

Comment: If there were, wouldn't that notification be completely useless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way - it's an intentional security feature.  Tell your client they're going to have to live with it.

Users don't want their location to be leaked to third party sites without explicit permission.